# How to enrich the csv content data with additional fields and convert into text file with pipe as delimiter using apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp, bindy

I have a csv file with input content separated with comma ",". I want to convert that into text file with "|" delimiter. I'm using apache camel CsvDataFormat to convert the given csv data format.I can be able to convert the csv content to pipe delimited string. I have two more constants which I have assigned to two variables.I would like to enrich the content of the output data with two additional fields as shown in expected output.

**Input**

**test.csv**

```
Jack Dalton, 115, mad at Averell 
Joe Dalton, 105, calming Joe 
William Dalton, 105, keeping Joe from killing 
Averell Averell Dalton, 80, playing with Rantanplan 
Lucky Luke, 120, capturing the Daltons
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test{
    private String name = "Hell0";
    private String address = "134 johen rd";
}
```

**ConverterRoute.java**

```
public class ConverterRoute implements RoutesBuilder {

    private static final String SOURCE_INPUT_PATH = "file://inbox?fileName=test.csv";

    private static final String SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH = "file://outbox?fileName=file.txt";

    public void addRoutesToCamelContext(CamelContext context) throws Exception {

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                try {
                    CsvDataFormat csvDataFormat = new CsvDataFormat();
                    csvDataFormat.setDelimiter('|');
                    csvDataFormat.setHeaderDisabled(true);

                    from(SOURCE_INPUT_PATH).
                            unmarshal().csv().
                            marshal(csvDataFormat).
                            to(SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH)
                            .end();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Output**

**file.txt**

```
Jack Dalton| 115 | mad at Averell 
Joe Dalton| 105 | calming Joe
William Dalton | 105 | keeping Joe from killing
Averell Averell Dalton| 80| playing with Rantanplan
Lucky Luke| 120| capturing the Daltons
```

**Expected Output**

**file.txt**

```
Jack Dalton| 115 | mad at Averell | Hell0 | 134 johen rd
Joe Dalton| 105 | calming Joe | Hell0 | 134 johen rd
William Dalton | 105 | keeping Joe from killing | Hell0 | 134 johen rd
Averell Averell Dalton| 80| playing with Rantanplan | Hell0 | 134 johen rd
Lucky Luke| 120| capturing the Daltons | Hell0 | 134 johen rd
```

In the above output file.txt the last two columns are the two constants which I have in my Test.java pojo class. I would like to enrich my pojo fields into the final output. Is there a way I can achieve the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your route after the step

```
unmarshal().csv()
```

you got a `List<List<String>>` as message body. Every list entry of the outer list represents a CSV line and each inner list contains the values of a line.

What you want to do is to add two values to each inner list.

Since your values are the same for every "line", it is probably the most simple approach to write a plain Java Bean that takes the `List<List<String>>`, iterates over the outer list and adds the two values (list entries) to each inner list.

in your Camel route you call this bean with

```
.bean(YourBean.class, "methodname")
```

but `methodname` is only needed when the Bean has multiple methods.

And then your route continues with

```
.marshal(csvDataFormat)
.to(SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH)
```

This should generate the file you want.

By the way, the `.end()` at the end of the route is not needed.